# Detect ontouchstart in PHP?

Tags: php, touch, screen, detect

In JavaScript, this is the best way to detect if the users device has a touch screen. It will not use the useragent and try to determine if the device supports a touch screen.

```
 if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
      alert('Touch Screen');
 }
```

How does one detect if the users device has a touch screen using PHP?

Comment: why do you need it in php?

Comment: I want to know since if it is true, I can echo some elements, if it is not true, I will echo a banner saying this webpage has touch screen interaction.

Comment: PD of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](//stackoverflow.com/q/13840429)